# How to pass Objective C's class instance to c++ method?

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to pass Objective C object instance to C++ method trough params. How I can do it?

This code doesn't work, and I know it. I'm just showing what I want.

```
MyObjcClass *instance = [[MyObjcClass alloc] init];
myCppClassInstance.myCppMethod(instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a keyword, so it won't work I agree. But for me there are no other issue in your sample code.

Juste declare your cpp method

```
void myCppMethod(MyObjcClass *obj) {

}
```

and use it like you did

```
MyObjcClass *obj = [[MyObjcClass alloc] init];
myCppMethod(obj);
```

Comment: class word was to show example. of cource I know it :D. But your code doesn't work

Comment: fail at compile or runtime ?

Comment: it doesn't see MyObcClass header in myCppMethod's class. Check updated code please

Comment: Remember to put .mm extension to file using c++
And try : 
`myCppClassInstance->myCppMethod(instance);` :)